# Minimum requirements for custom networking stack to send UDP packets?

Tags: linux, networking, udp, ip, mbed

(edit: solved -- see below)

This is my situation:

```
TL-MR3020 -----ethernet----- mbed
OpenWRT                      C/C++ custom networking stack
192.168.2.1                  192.168.2.16
```

- [TL-MR3020](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-mr3020) is a Linux embedded router
- [mbed](http://mbed.org/platforms/mbed-LPC1768/) is an ARM microcontroller.

On the network I just want them to exchange messages using UDP packets on port 2225. In particular, TL-MR3020 has to periodically send packets every second to 192.168.2.16:2225, while mbed has to periodically send packets every 50ms to 192.168.2.1:2225.

Everything was good untill I removed the network stack library from mbed (lwIP, not so lightweight for me) and written a new minimal stack.
My new stacks sends 5 gratuitous ARP reply just after the ethernet link gets up, then starts sending and receiving udp packets.

Now TL-MR3020 doesn't receive any UDP packet. In particular, with `ifconfig` I can see packets coming, but my application can't get them.
Also, if I connect my laptop instead of the TL-MR3020, I can see the UDP packets coming, using Wireshark. There's nothing wrong, except done for my application.

I have a node.js script that has to receive the packets, but it doesn't receive nothing, but if I send UDP packets from local to local, the script receives them.
I think that my application is OK also because neither SOCAT can receive the UDP packets using `socat - UDP-LISTEN:2225`.

I've already checked on TL-MR3020:

- arp table has the correct ip-mac assiciation
- destination MAC address matches the incoming interface
- destination IP address matches the incoming interface
- IP checksum: wireshark says good=false, bad=false
- UDP checksum: wireshark says good=false, bad=false

So, I'm asking... what are the minimum requirements for a custom networking stack to send UDP packets?

**SOLVED:**

- You need a good checksum in the IP header.
- UDP checksum, my case, can be set to zero.
- `tcpdump` is very helpful (thanks to AndrewMcDonnell)

Comment: I know you used Wireshark on a PC, but are you able install & run tcpdump on the MR3020 and paste a full trace?

You will want to run `tcpdump -l -n -i ethX` or it may appear to hang

Comment: On TL-MR3020: `tcpdump -l -n -vv -i eth0` says 0 packets dropped by kernel, 38 packets captured... and... bad cksum, all the packets, both udp and ip. Is that the problem? I ignored the checksum in my code because wireshark says "validation disabled". Are checksum needed? In that case my "networking stack" won't stay in single 200lines function.
Also, I'm going to publish the full trace.
Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm now generating good checksum for IP header. UDP checksum is set to zero. But still the same, nothing new.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewMcDonnell, I did't considered tcpdump.
(Problem solved)